# How to prove formally that division is not commutative?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binary-operations

I am studying quantitative reasoning and I am wondering how to prove formally that division is not commutative. Everyone knows that 7/3 is not the same as 3/7, but is there a formal way to conceptualize it? Thank you

Comment: You don't need nothing more than $3/7 \neq 7/3$ to show non-commutativity.

Comment: To prove commutativity fails is very easy, as Crostul points out. Because commutativity requires that $(a,b)=(b,a)$, for *every* pair $a$ and $b$, then *any* counterexample works.

Comment: Ok @Crostul, but is there a way to formalize, for instance, if you define an operator that you are not aware of the result on your domain space, can you still prove some properties?

Comment: @AlviseSembenico: You have to first define exactly what $\frac ab$ means in order to prove that it isn't commutative.

Comment: @AlviseSembenico: You have to first define exactly what $\frac ab$ means in order to prove that it isn't commutative.

Answer (score 4):

Asserting that $\frac73\neq\frac37$ is a full proof of the fact that division is not commutative. A simpler proof would be the fact that $\frac21\neq\frac12$.

Comment: To formally argue that $\frac37\neq\frac73$, should you not first define what each means? I’ve always learned division is the inverse of multiplication, so should we not relate everything back to multiplication?

Comment: We could do that of course, but I think that it is simpler to say that $\frac73>1>\frac37$.

Answer (score 0):

Let us define $$\frac{a}{b}:=a b^{-1}$$ for $b\neq0$.. Here, $b^{-1}$ just denotes the element that produces unity upon multiplication by $b$ (stated succinctly, $b\cdot b^{-1}=1$). Since $ab^{-1}\neq a^{-1}b$, we have that division is not commutative. Indeed, take $a\neq bk$ for any $k\in\Bbb Z$. Then $$ab^{-1}=a^{-1}b\Longrightarrow (ab^{-1})^2=1\Longrightarrow a=\pm b,$$which is a contradiction to our assumption that $a\neq bk$. We have used the commutative property of multiplication here.

An alternative, but essentially equivalent method: if $ab^{-1}=a^{-1}b$, then we have $a^2=b^2$. Now all we need to do is to demonstrate a pair of elements $a,b$ whose squares are not equal; in particular, $3^2=9\neq 49=7^2$, so $\frac 37\neq\frac73$. Since it fails for *some* pair of elements $a,b$, division cannot be commutative in general.

Comment: Thank you Clayton, your answer is in the direction I am looking for. Nonetheless, taking $$a=bk$$ is a violation of your assumption, therefore not general, right?

Comment: @AlviseSembenico: In fact, if $k=\pm1$, then we have $ab^{-1}=a^{-1}b$, so we have to exclude certain cases (I wanted to say $\gcd(a,b)=1$, but it felt circular since we're talking about division). My recent edit might help clarify things.

Comment: @AlviseSembenico: I was being silly. I just need $b\neq 0$ at first; we only need to demonstrate a single case where $ab^{-1}\neq a^{-1}b$ to show noncommutativity.